# Integration of iCloud in my android application

Tags: android, icloud, icloud-api

I need to integrate `iCloud` in my android application. Is it possible to integrate iCloud in my android application ? I find on net but not getting any solutions or any articles regarding this.

One thing I come to know that in IOS it is possible to integrate iCloud. But I cant figure out it is possible in android or not and if yes then how it is possible..

Please help me to find this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no iCloud APIs for Android.

Answer (score 0):

> ### [icloud4j](https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/icloud4j)
>
> Not sure how useful it is for Android, but I've started a Java open source project based off the Python [pyicloud](https://github.com/picklepete/pyicloud) implementation. It's still in the early stages at the moment but you can check it out here:

- https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/icloud4j

To access iPhone backups there is the InflatableDonkey library:

- https://github.com/horrorho/InflatableDonkey